Contraction and isometry
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two untial commutative Banach algebras. Suppose $X\subset Y$ and $X$ countractively embeds $Y$. Why is it not the case that the embedding is isometric?
From what I see, since $X$ is a subspace of $Y$, if $T: X\rightarrow Y$ is a contraction, any element of $X$ can be in $Y$. So $T$ should be an isometry. What is wrong with this?
Any help will be appreiciated!

This seems a notational issue. If I write $X \subset Y$, I’d assume the embedding is isometric, but the author seems intended for the embedding to just be contractive. In that case it certainly could happen that the embedding is only contractive, but not isometric. For example, $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z}) \subset C^\ast(\mathbb{Z})$.

I guess my confusion is that $X$ and $Y$ share the same norm, and one is a subspace of another, why is it possible that it's not an isometry? Thanks for your help!

That’s what I meant by notational confusion. Usually, $X \subset Y$ implies the norm on $X$ is the restriction of the norm on $Y$ to $X$, but it seems, based on what you wrote, that the author only intended $X \subset Y$ to mean $X$ is a linear subspace of $Y$, with no constraints on whether the norm on $X$ agrees with the restriction of the norm on $Y$.

(If that’s not what you believe it means, you should provide more context regarding the question.)
